# What tool can suggest index and covering indexes for dynamicly created queries?

Tags: java, mysql, dynamic, indexing

Our web application basically dynamically generates tables and relations.  It also generate indexes on the basic level.  We are looking for a MySQL profiler that will be able to suggest indexes.  We have come across this two profilers :

[MYSQL JET PROFILER](http://www.jetprofiler.com) : will not tell use what index or covering index will do the job.

[ROT](http://ritmark.com/) : will not work on a live database, basically you have to give the query and schema in diff files.

None of these above will do the job.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QOT](http://ritmark.com) supports server-side schemata. Check out the latest Launchpad version. Also it never required "diff" files. You just had to provide normal SQL scripts, like ones generated by mysqldump. Now both ways (i.e. scripts and live connection) supported.

BR,
Vladimir